# scaling tx volume - Possible methods?

Tags: network

Reports of slight network congestion since BAT ICO started funding. What are the various ways to easily handle this capacity? (Batch processing -As we know their funding Address?)

Comment: I agree this is an important discussion, but it's not very well suited for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to deal with network congestion if you want to participate in the crowdsale was to schedule transaction with Parity Scheduler or Ethereum Alarm Clock and set up high or very high gas price so miners will more likely include into a block. Crowdsale for $35M was finished in two blocks.